# How to assign an object to a html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of objects as a response from server, I'm trying to assign an array of objects that is inside that response to a html element. I tried `data-code="${JSON.stringify(item.ObjectProp)}"`.

But I get either [Object object] when console logging it, or `{[`(first 2 elements of the array).

Some code example:

```
async getRequestFunction() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  data.InvoiceList.forEach(item => { 
    table.innerHTML += `<div data-code="${item.Lines}">${item.Name}</div>`; 
  }
  console.log(document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('data-code'));
  // Output is either [Object object] or '{[', depending if I JSON.stringify the   
  `item.Lines` or not.
}
```

I've also tried `JSON.parse` on the getAttribute line. The error I get is: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse`

EDIT:
Found out the problem is in here:

```
<div class="table-sent-item" data-code="[{" article":"","barcode":null,"code":"00160047","name":"imprimanta="" pos="" orderman="" srp-330ii="" serial="" ethernet=""}]"></div>
```

After data-code it, the `[{` is in double quotes, so getAttribute doesn't go further that.

Basically, I have to replace all the double quotes after `[{` with single quotes.

EDIT2: I've replaced the double quotes inside the json object with single quotes like this: `data-code="${JSON.stringify(item.Lines).replace(/"/g, "'")}"`.
And then `JSON.parse` the result(and reverse replace the quotes). It works perfectly fine when there's only one object in the array.

But I get JSON.parse error when there are multiple objects in the array from data-code. `Unexpected string in JSON`.

```
/* NEW EDIT */
```

Comment: First problem - *DO NOT* do `.innerHTML += /*...*/` in a loop.

Comment: Can you explain why? I have a table that should render dynamically, depending on what's on the server.

Comment: Each time you do that, the entire DOM string will be re-read and re-evaluated. That's a lot of work for just adding a few elements. Moreover, you're very likely to get problems because the HTML you have there will be parsed and "completed" if it's currently invalid. This might lead to unintended and hard to catch errors. `el.innerHTML += "<div>"; el.innerHTML += "some content";  el.innerHTML += "</div>";` will not add `<div>some content</div>` but `<div></div>some content` because the first `<div>` is incomplete, so it's auto-closesd. Then you add the content and the final tag is ignored.

Comment: I missed the `</div>` there. Everything is wrapped up. Sorry for the obscureness.

Comment: @Dipzera also worth mentioning this could lead to session hijacking attacks and XSS. Never manipulate HTML that comes from the server like this! If `item.Name` contains `<script>while(true){alert("annoying");}</script>` it would be evaluated! And that's just the non-dangerous example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [1,2,3]
var str = JSON.stringify(data)

document.body.innerHTML = `<div id="box" data-code=${str}></div>`

alert(document.querySelector('#box').dataset.code)

console.log(JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#box').dataset.code))
```

Comment: u can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a JSON value, that had `double 'single quotes'` in it. The DOM recognized it as ending `"double quotes"`. Replaced that with another symbol,
`replace(/'/g, "\~")`. Then reverse replaced the output.